# Uninstall nuget packages installed with nuget.exe

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I was having trouble with nuget Visual Studio 2017 and wanted to test if it was our proxy server or not.  I downloaded nuget.exe and dropped it at the root of my C drive.  I executed nuget.exe install Microsoft.AspNetCore and it asked for my proxy server username and password.  I supplied it, and it proceeded to create dozens of directories in C:\ with that package and all of it's dependencies (can I get a DOH!)  Problem is, there's no uninstall in nuget.exe.  The package manager in VS isn't available unless you have a solution open, and the package manager console (powershell) won't uninstall unless you have a solution open.  Can I just clobber all those directories and their contents?  Or will that just make things different and somehow worse:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I just clobber all those directories and their contents? Or will that just make things different and somehow worse

Yes, you can (If you confirm that you no longer need these packages).

According to the document [install command (NuGet CLI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-install):

> The install command does not modify a project file or packages.config;
>   in this way it's similar to restore in that it **only adds packages to
>   disk but does not change a project's dependencies**.

When you use `nuget.exe` install some packages, it just **download those packages to the disk and not change anything in the project**, this is similar to some files you downloaded from the internet.

So, if you do not need those packages any more, you can just delete them from the disk manually.

Besides, there is an option [delete command (NuGet CLI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-delete), which can be used to deletes or unlists a package from a package source. The exact behavior depends on the source. For local folders, for instance, the package is deleted; for nuget.org the package is unlisted. But it only delete the file `.nupkg` and will keep the folders and other files of other packages, like `lib` folder. If you want remove the package completely, just delete those packages manually.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I saw the delete command, but I read it as deleting from the source, which in this case was api.nuget.org, so not applicable. I'll just clobber the directories.

Comment: @NoloProblemo, No, Notice that "The exact behavior depends on the source. **For local folders, for instance, the package is deleted**; for nuget.org the package is unlisted.", So if you specify the source like -source C:\Microsoft.AspNetCore with command delete, it will delete the package. And I said that If you want remove the package completely, just delete those packages manually.