# Uninstall packages installed with nuget.exe outside project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, nugetgallery

This is essentially the same question as [Uninstall nuget packages installed with nuget.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52303652/uninstall-nuget-packages-installed-with-nuget-exe) but that question only has a dubious answer which is incorrect.

Basically, I was mislead by build error messages and bad documentation to download `nuget.exe` and run `nuget.exe install` outside any project, only to find out that there is no obvious command to uninstall the packages and that package contents got dumped in whatever was current dir at the time of running `nuget.exe install`

So how does one properly uninstall packages installed that way.  By properly uninstall I mean removing the package contents and any nuget internal state related to the package being installed.

Comment: What do you mean by "uninstall"? Removing it from `YourProject.csproj` resp. `packages.config`?

Comment: There is no project.  For some reason, nuget.exe (version 6.2.0.146) allowed the install command to be executed outside any project, and I need to undo the effects to get the machine back to the state before running that command.  Not some similar-but-different broken state as would presumably result from deleting the created directories without finding the hidden NuGet state stored in some config directory or registry key.  Only when I searched for more documentation did I find that Microsoft refuses to even talk about how to install or uninstall packages computer-wide.

Comment: What’s your steps to run nuget.exe install outside any project. Install command means downloads and installs a package into a project(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-install ). Maybe you can use commend like “nuget delete packageID -Source folder path” to delete the package in your local folder, or you can use the command “nuget locals all -clear” to clear local caches(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders).

Comment: Running nuget.exe outside any project is trivial: Open a generic Windows command console, CD to an arbitrary directory (or stay wherever Windows leaves me upon opening the console) and type in the command C:\some\path\nuget.exe install some.package 1234 Thus installing version 1234 of that package.

Answer (score 0):

According to a an answer from Microsoft when I posted the lack of a "nuget.exe uninstall" command, "nuget.exe install" outside any project only does a trivial download and unpack, thus doing "rd /s /q some.package.1234" is sufficient.